# Plesk - Forward subdomain to another port

Tags: port, subdomain

I'm using an ubuntu web server with plesk 11.5.* - **I want to forward a subdomain to a nodejs application with the port 2368**. 
On my old debian systems i would create a vhost for ip:2368 and set the wanted subdomain as servername, correct?

But how would i do this with plesk. As far as i know i have to edit the config files manually. I've created the /var/www/vhosts/system/domain.net/conf/vhost.conf file and tried to insert my  tag there but that does not work, it is already wrapped by a virtualhost tag.

`<VirtualHost> cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section`

I cannot find any good way to change the configuration. Even http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/de-DE/online/plesk-linux-advanced-administration-guide/index.htm?fileName=72064.htm did not help.

So all at all i need a domain like app.domain.tld that refers to app.domain.tld:2368

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to edit the nginx template file for the host as explained here:
[Nginx to address Nodejs app](https://serverfault.com/questions/541268/nginx-to-address-nodejs-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new *domain* app.domain.tld with standard forwarding to "http://app.domain.tld:2368"

[image]

Comment: ty, that works but i would like to hide the port for my nodejs app, if possible

Comment: In this case you have to setup nginx virtual host to serve your nodejs as upstream in separate server-wide config(its out of plesk). I suggest you to create another question(or google) with this detail and tag "nginx" just to warn nginx-experienced guys. The question wording should be in terms of upstream not forwarding, because forwarding will always expose port number.

Comment: thank you! my search for a solution continues with the new terms :)