# Nginx to address Nodejs app

Tags: nginx, subdomain, node.js

I'm using an Ubuntu web server with Plesk 11.5.x. I've added Nodejs and now i want to adress the Nodejs app with a subdomain.

Website: `domain.tld`

Nodejs App: `app.domain.tld`

Currently working: `domain.tld:2368`, but i want to hide the port with the help of a subdomain.

---

I should be able to do the following:

```
upstream app_myApp {
    server 127.0.0.1:2368;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name app.domain.tld;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_myApp/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

My problem is where to place this, because i am using Plesk. In Plesk 11.5's `.../system/domain.tld/conf/vhost_nginx.conf` are upstream and server commands not allowed. And `location /` isn't possible either.

---

I guess I would need something like `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.tld`. I have no idea where to add this without breaking plesk or my config being overwritten on an automatic plesk reconfig.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit nginx template file

```
mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain
cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain
```

in new file /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php
find following lines:

```
    location / {
<?php echo $VAR->includeTemplate('domain/service/proxy.php', $OPT); ?>
    }
```

and adjust it to Your needs:

```
    location / {
<?php if ('mydomain.tld' == $VAR->domain->asciiName ) {
         echo $VAR->includeTemplate('PATHTONODECONFIG.php', $OPT); ?>
       } else {
         echo $VAR->includeTemplate('domain/service/proxy.php', $OPT); ?>
     }
```

I suggest to parametrise this condition, to be more flexible

Comment: does a plesk update overwrite the nginxDomainVirtualHost.php file?

Comment: yes, you are right. it wil override these changes with new version.
you should put custom template in this folder
  /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/
i will fix manual too

Comment: thank you - does nginx use automatically the custom template afterwards? what would i have to put in the nodeconfig file. i assume sth like "proxy_pass http://mydomain.tld:2368;" or "proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;" in my case - but that didn't work

Comment: Worked now with
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368/;
      proxy_redirect off;